# How do I add a custom button to the admin listing?

Tags: django-admin

What I want is to put a custom button in each row of a page of the admin listing.
These buttons will have a function associate to it acting over that line.
I've already knew the "admin actions", but it's not what I want, ok?

Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can declare in your ModelAdmin a function to generate the html for your button, e.g.

```
    def button(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<input type="...">')
    title.short_description = 'Action'
    title.allow_tags = True
```

And then put it in your in your `list_display`-tuple.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    list_display=('name', 'button')
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options

Comment: Thank you!
Sorry for being late to see the answer, i've found another way to solve my problem. Anyway, it could help ^^

Comment: Just to say: The client hadn't liked the way I've used to solve.... 
So it has helped me in the same problem! ;)