# Adding action buttons/links to Django admin list

Tags: python, django

In my Django admin interface I have created a custom action `make_published` as per the [example in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) and this works fine using the action drop down at the top of the page.

Is there a way to add a column to the admin list display that contains a button or link with the text "Make published" that will apply that action to that particular row?

**Edit:** I have attempted to do this with the method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821104/how-do-i-add-a-custom-button-to-the-admin-listing), but have been unable to successfully submit a form for an individual row due to the fact that the whole table is a form.

Comment: You may refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821104/how-do-i-add-a-custom-button-to-the-admin-listing

Comment: Right, but then I would have to write the form and the backend to handle the submission myself wouldn't I? I was hoping that there was something more built-in that I could leverage.

Comment: you could give 'list_editable', if you just want set the Boolean value.